# Undefined index PHP/MySQL when trying to query database

Tags: php, arrays

This one is working fine #1 but when I try to relate other tables on the second one, it gives an error

Notice: Undefined index: recipe.id in C:\xampp\htdocs\hyukies\public\samples.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: recipe.ingredientid in C:\xampp\htdocs\hyukies\public\samples.php on line 31
RecipeID:
IngredientID:

Notice: Undefined index: recipe.id in C:\xampp\htdocs\hyukies\public\samples.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: recipe.ingredientid in C:\xampp\htdocs\hyukies\public\samples.php on line 31
RecipeID:
IngredientID:

Notice: Undefined index: recipe.id in C:\xampp\htdocs\hyukies\public\samples.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: recipe.ingredientid in C:\xampp\htdocs\hyukies\public\samples.php on line 31
RecipeID:
IngredientID:

```
 <?php
 $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id, location FROM location");
 $userinfo = array();
 while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $userinfo[] = $row_user;
 foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
     echo "ID: {$user['id']}<br />"
    . "Location: {$user['location']}<br /><br />";
 }
 ?>
```

This one is not working error problem please help......

```
 <?php
 $sql_2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT recipe.id, recipe.ingredientid, ingredients.id, ingredients.quantity, ingredients.`name` FROM recipe INNER JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.id = recipe.ingredientid");
 $userinfo_2 = array();
 while ($row_user_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_2))
     $userinfo_2[] = $row_user_2;
 foreach ($userinfo_2 as $user_2) {
     echo "RecipeID: {$user_2['recipe.id']}<br />"
     . "IngredientID: {$user_2['recipe.ingredientid']}<br /><br />";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I tried but still the same. :(

Comment: Looks like you're accessing columns in the array that don't exist. Try `print_r($user_2)` to see what you can access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the back ticks from 'name' in your query

```
$sql_2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT recipe.id, recipe.ingredientid, ingredients.id, ingredients.quantity, ingredients.`name` FROM recipe INNER JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.id = recipe.ingredientid");
```

Should be

```
$sql_2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT recipe.id, recipe.ingredientid, ingredients.id, ingredients.quantity, ingredients.name FROM recipe INNER JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.id = recipe.ingredientid");
```

Also, remove 'recipe' from `$user_2['recipe.id']`. It should be `$user2['id']`, but it won't be clear which id you are getting. To selected them independently you can use 'AS' in your query to give them a unique identifier.

```
 SELECT recipe.id AS id1, ingedients.id AS id2
```

Comment: how can I call the row number? $user_2['0'], $user_2['1']? tnx

Comment: Use a counter. So before the foreach loop put `$i = 0` and the inside the foreach out `$i++`. This will add 1 to $i on each loop, so as you you can tell which row it is but echoing $i inside the loop

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with backtick-wrapping column names.  Implementing the first piece of advice from this answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the associative array just contain the column names, not the table names. So it should be:

```
 echo "RecipeID: {$user_2['id']}<br />"
 . "IngredientID: {$user_2['ingredientid']}<br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

The table names are not included in the result set, so the columns are only named `id`, `ingredientid` etc. You really should use `as` for naming them, like `recipe.id as recipeid`. There is no warning about there being to `id` fields and PHP will map them together.

You don't really need both id fields anyway, since you also have the ingredientid, but most probably you will get ingredients.id in the `id` field also since it's latter.

So update your query to something like

```
SELECT recipe.id AS recipeid,
    recipe.ingredientid,
    ingredients.quantity,
    ingredients.name
  FROM recipe
    INNER JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.id = recipe.ingredientid
```

and then use recipeid to get the recipe.id. This will always be better, since it's clear what id you are getting.